# entering credentials with IWebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have some web site that needs credentials:

[image]

Using a selenium IWebDriver, is there a way to enter the credentials?

Comment: try this form of `URL`: `http://username:password@www.website.com`

Comment: I would like to mark this as an answer since this solve my problem a while ago. If you put it as an answer I will gladly accept it. Else I can set it myself in few days. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following Basic [access authentication method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#URL_encoding):

```
http://username:password@www.website.com
```